# How to save a MediaStream for later use

Tags: javascript, stream, audio-recording, webapi, mediastream

My apologize for the bad title, I wasn't too sure how to summarize it without making it misleading or incomplete.

Another apology in advance as this is my first post. I've lurked for a good 5 years but always found a post that answered my question. I tried my best to keep it concise without skipping over relevant information.

**Background**

What I want to do is to do audio analysis on a a recording, specifically pitch detection. If I just did analysis directly on the stream from the recording, I would have no problem. However, due to performance reasons, I would like to first record and then analyze the recording. What I have currently is a MediaRecorder called `recording` recording the stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.

When there is data available i push to an ordinary array called chunks:

```js
recording.ondataavailable = ( e ) => {
   chunks.push(e.data)
}
```

When the recording stops I save it in a blob and then save the blob in an element:

```js
const blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: "audio/mp3"});
const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
AUDIOSAVE.src = audioURL
```

and this is where I get stuck. I can play the AUDIOSAVE element and then take its stream with

```js
const stream = srcElemenent.captureStream()
```

I can feed this `stream` into the model I'm using ([ml5.js CREPE based pitch detector](https://learn.ml5js.org/#/reference/pitch-detection), which uses said stream as an input) and it gives back the predicted frequencies.

**BUT** I REALLY would like to mute the output. Adding the `muted` attribute to the element seems to kill the stream (I guess because "nothing" is playing).

(btw, the previous code snipped confuses me, I'll clarify in question 2 below).

I'll happily add more information if needed.

**Main question:**

How should I proceed (assuming I'm thinking about this the correct way)?

**Secondary question:**

How do MediaStreams even work in JS? Isn't a stream supposed to be continuous? How can it be returned and then just used on a next line?